# navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem crashes on click / pan etc

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, exc-bad-access, uinavigationitem

I am trying to make a uinavigationgroup in a subview of my main viewcontroller.

```
catViewController *view = [[catViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view];
[_pageContainerView addSubview:navCtrl.view];
view.view.hidden = NO;
```

So far so good, I've got a uinavigationcontroller in my subview, only I want to set a custom leftbutton to make a facebook style menu to I have to have a pan recognizer and a touchupinside, lets start with the touchinside action:

```
catViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set class variables
    appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // create button with touch handler
   btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,42,33)];

   if( [self.navigationController.viewControllers count] == 1 ){
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_menu"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMenuPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }else{
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    // set the custom left button
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
}

- (IBAction)btnBackPress:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"back press");
}

- (IBAction)btnMenuPress:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"menu press");
}
```

So far so good, the button is in place and my controller is visible, only when I click the button, I get a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address=0x18)

So now I am completely perplexed, have been tinkering with this for over 4 hours now, time to call in the cavalry.

Thanks in advance! Rene

Comment: I'll guess that your `catViewController` is going away prematurely.  Create a `dealloc` method in it and `NSLog` some message to see if the object is being removed from memory.  (Or turn on zombies in your build scheme.)

Comment: Phillip, it is being removed from memory, how is this possible its the rootcontroller of my uinavigationgroup, i can only assume that the rootcontroller of a uinav is a string link :S

Comment: You don't actually show what happens to `navCtrl`.  Are you sure it's being used as the window's root view controller?  Try logging the address of `navCtrl` and the `self.navigationController` that's available in `viewDidLoad` to make sure they're the same.

Comment: Ah... no its not the windows root view controller.... now it all makes sence! Ive made a strong pointer to the rootviewcontroller of the navcontroller in the private decleration of my mainviewcontroller and now all is working as it should! Thanks!!!